# AccessDeniedException: 403 The project to be billed is associated with a closed billing account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I have opened a new google cloud account and I am about to set up a VM on that. Before that I wanted to create a bucket and I will be copying from one bucket to another bucket.

I am able to create a bucket and while copying I am facing issue as below:

AccessDeniedException: 403 The project to be billed is associated with a closed billing account.

So I have tried the following options:

To reopen a closed account:

Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console.
Open the console left side menu and select Billing.
Choose Manage billing accounts.
From the list near the middle of the page, select Show all accounts.
Click the billing account name.
Click Reopen billing account.

After clicking on billing account name, I could not find a "Reopen billing account option". I am stuck at this point. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Reading here .... https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account we seem to find that only billing accounts closed by the billing administrator can be re-opened.  Do we know how the account was closed to begin with?

Comment: I have opened a new mail id for this cloud platform, and I am not sure how this billing account is closed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was using the Shrine GCP for my Rails project and this error occurred because I had not pointed to the correct bucket in the initializer shrine.rb.

For anyone who is not using my stack, then the issue was that the bucket I had declared did not exist in my GCP project. So be sure that either 1) You are pointing to the right bucket or 2) create the bucket in the project Cloud Storage.

I have no idea why Google gives this error message lol

Comment: You have saved my day :)

Comment: you saved my sanity and my a lot of grief.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Project's Billing Settings](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#change_the_billing_account_for_a_project),  **you must be an owner on the project and a billing administrator on the destination billing account**.

Just make sure of the billing account you have linked to that project.

Answer (score 2):

If you are the owner of the Billing account, just go to the console (Google Cloud Platform) on the browser and select the project. Click the `Activate Billing` button on the top and refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

- Switch project to the one needed
- Click billing
- Link billing

Actions to be done via GCP web UI

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when requesting a file that didn't exist in my bucket. Had nothing to do with billing and other files with correct paths were available.

So double-check if this file exists in your bucket.