# GCP Billing error when Billing is enabled

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I have this Python code:

```
def upload_to_gcs(bucket_name, local_file_path, gcs_file_name):
    """
    Uploads local files to Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param local_file_path: string
    :param gcs_file_name: string
    :return: None
    """
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(gcs_file_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(local_file_path)
```

which is failing with this error:

```
Exception has occurred: Forbidden
403 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/monzo/o?uploadType=multipart: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state closed",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state closed",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "accountDisabled",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have confirmed and Billing is definitely enabled, see below.

[image: billing_!]
[image: project billing]

I also went through all possible solutions in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732504/google-cloud-403-error-the-billing-account-for-the-owning-project-is-disabled-in#:%7E:text=The%20%22The%20billing%20account%20for,is%20recommended%20to%20try%20again.). Nothing worked, double checked the bucket exists and all that. Finally also tried reaching Google but got stuck in chatbot which didn't help.

EDIT: Tried checking in Cloud Shell and got this back

```
miguel@cloudshell:~$ gcloud beta billing projects describe miguel-377315
billingAccountName: billingAccounts/0193C3-8A2BD3-44C7DB
billingEnabled: true
name: projects/miguel-377315/billingInfo
projectId: miguel-377315
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How does `upload_to_gcs()` know the account credentials?

Comment: They are loaded as env variables

Comment: Are you absolutely sure those variables are correct?

Comment: I am... That service account is also being used by Terraform in a separate repo and it is working there.

Comment: The billing is enabled but is attached to the project?

Comment: It is enabled and attached to the project yes. You can see that in the screenshots above.

Comment: Also, I just trying listing blobs which worked... So that confirms credentials are not the issue.

Answer (score 4):

It was a bug which was causing the bucket name to be incorrect. Nothing to do with billing. When I fixed the bucket name, everything worked.

Comment: What was wrong with your bucket name and how did you fix it?